# Rename A Table Prefix Using Wildcards

Tags: sql, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to change the prefix on all the tables in my site. I thought I could do this:

```
rename table 'wp_%' to 'wp_13_%'
```

But that doesn't seem to work. I'd love input into what i may be doing wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since mysql doesn't use wildcards like % in rename table why don't you export the database do a global seach in your favorite text editor wp_ and replace with wp_13_?

Then you can reimport it.

That should do it.

Comment: Super simple, most definitely the easiest way to update table prefixes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I know you're using MySQL, though I have something like that written for SQL Server (using T-SQL.) It's like using a bulldozer to open a door, but it works. You could possibly use it as a basis for a MySQL query... definitely not an instantly usable answer, but something that you could base the logic for a stored procedure off if you wanted.

```
DECLARE @FrontWord nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @NewFrontWord nvarchar(20)

SET @FrontWord = 'wp_'
SET @NewFrontWord = 'wp_13_'

DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor
FOR (
    SELECT TABLE_NAME
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE'
    AND TABLE_NAME LIKE @FrontWord + '%'
)

Open MY_CURSOR

DECLARE @tablename nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @lastpart nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @newtablename nvarchar(20)

Fetch NEXT FROM MY_Cursor INTO @tablename

    While (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -1)
    BEGIN
        IF (@@FETCH_STATUS <> -2)
        SET @lastpart = RIGHT(@tablename, LEN(@tablename) - LEN(@FrontWord))
        SET @newtablename = @NewFrontWord + @lastpart;
        PRINT @newtablename

        EXEC sp_rename @tablename, @newtablename

FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @tablename
END 

CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
GO
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Awesome. Remember, that won't work directly in MySQL because it's designed for SQL Server. I'm not really sure what extended language MySQL has (this is T-SQL, which is for SQL Server, Access has JET SQL, Oracle has something too but I can't remember what.) Are you able to run a small program in PHP that connects to the database, as it would definitely be possible to convert it to PHP.

Comment: Hmm I ran it in the mysql sql browser and got:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE @FrontWord nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @NewFrontWord nvarchar(20)

SET @Fron' at line 1 

any ideas how to remedy that?

Comment: Just saw your comment, I should probably try a php version of this.

Comment: What does the @ symbol do there, just specify the a variable like `$` in PHP?

Answer (score 1):

mysql rename syntax doesn't support wildcards like the % you used.
You can still rename several tables in one command.

e.g. if you have table wp_A, wp_B you can rename to wp_13_A, wp_13_B

```
RENAME TABLE 'wp_A' TO 'wp_13_A', 'wp_B' TO 'wp_13_B'
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the neccesary DDL code with sql. Not pretty, but powerful :)

Just copy&paste the result.

```
set session sql_mode='PIPES_AS_CONCAT';

select 'alter table ' 
     || table_name 
     || ' rename to wp_13_' 
     || substr(table_name, 4) 
     || ';' as ddl
  from information_schema.tables 
 where table_schema = 'BLOG';


+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ddl                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| alter table wp_commentmeta rename to wp_13_commentmeta;               |
| alter table wp_comments rename to wp_13_comments;                     |
| alter table wp_links rename to wp_13_links;                           |
| alter table wp_options rename to wp_13_options;                       |
| alter table wp_postmeta rename to wp_13_postmeta;                     |
| alter table wp_posts rename to wp_13_posts;                           |
| alter table wp_term_relationships rename to wp_13_term_relationships; |
| alter table wp_term_taxonomy rename to wp_13_term_taxonomy;           |
| alter table wp_terms rename to wp_13_terms;                           |
| alter table wp_usermeta rename to wp_13_usermeta;                     |
| alter table wp_users rename to wp_13_users;                           |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```